# Keras CNN val_accuracy, loss, accuracy stuck

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am performing binary classification using CNN in Keras. The dataset has got nearly 8k images in total but it's not balanced - one class has around 1500 samples while the other has 6500 samples. I am not setting a random seed before training. Now, when I ran this model a few days back, I got 99% accuracy. I ran it again the other day - got 99% accuracy. Just to be sure, I ran it 5 more times and every time it gave me the same results. Now, after a gap of 4 days when I am running it again to store parameters and plot graphs - my model is stuck at 85% accuracy and 67% validation accuracy. Nothing is changing over epochs, it's just stuck there. 
I am using flow_from_directory to load images on the fly and also performing some augmentation while loading the images. I am aware that the weights are randomly initialized every time and that is why I have stored the weights of best performing model. But I am just not able to reproduce the results. Any idea what's going wrong here?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(476,476,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss=binary_crossentropy,
              optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1):

99% accuracy on a real-world and imbalanced data set is very highly unlikely, especially considering that your ANN isn't anywhere close to state-of-the-art that e.g. yield close to 99% accuracy on datasets like [cats vs dogs challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats). Also, mind that with the latter you have ~25000 images in a balanced setup.

85% training accuracy and 67% validation accuracy sound like very reasonable numbers without knowing anything about your dataset. For sure you should try to address the imbalance by augmenting the class that's in minority.

So, why would you get 99% before? A glitch in the Matrix or extreme luck. If it's not reproducible, forget about that and focus on the results you're getting now. Last but not least, make sure to fix the seed on any random processes.

Comment: Well, I was able to reproduce the results by removing the dropout layer. 99% accuracy might not be possible on a real world dataset without any kind of pre-processing, the innovation here isn't in the model - it's in the preprocessing step which I cannot share over here. It's medical image data and 85% accuracy is not even close to being acceptable here. Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: I am getting 99% test accuracy for the majority class and 97% test accuracy for the minority class. If this was such a highly unlikely prospect then the test accuracy would have been very low. I request you to go through the latest publications in the field of biomedical image processing - to see how simple models with innovative tweaking are indeed giving 99% accuracy. Please don't make such misguiding statements like these -"99% accuracy on a real-world and imbalanced data set is very highly unlikely, especially considering that your ANN isn't anywhere close to state-of-the-art ".

Comment: @SamarjeetKaur The statement is based on reviewing good number of papers and experience in putting deep learning models in production. The papers you're referring to are notorious for having not reproducible results, with researchers very often struggling to properly validate the method. IBM Watson Health suffered huge layoffs exactly because reality of medical imaging is far from the training grounds. It's close to guaranteed that when you get images from totally new source (and e.g. camera calibration will be different, cases novel), you won't get anywhere the accuracy your ANN provides.

Comment: You're 100% right and I am well aware of that. In medical image processing, every result is subjective owing to the limited dataset - some produce results on 1000 images and some do on 10,000. I can't comment about the reproducibility  of the results that have been published - perhaps, they aren't, that's why such solutions haven't been implemented on a large scale. However, we must not forget that these non-reproducible researches drive the production level researches.

Comment: I can't get access to a huge amount of data right away but yes, if I show some results on the limited data that I have, I can surely earn the credibility - of being worthy of more data. Based on the results I quote now, I can share my uncertainities with the data providing organizations and ask them to supply more data in order to test the robustness of my model. The question that I had asked was completely technical, pertaining to the random initializations and perhaps the "extreme luck" which doesn't seem to end now - since I have managed to get the same results over 30 times now.

Comment: I tried all sorts of augmentation and different combinations of test, train and val sets. Somehow,my luck doesn't seem to end. I know the scores are unrealistic and that is exactly why I have my doubts, and I am testing it in every way possible but I can't seem to point out where I am going wrong and I also can't disregard reproducible results just by attributing it to my extreme luck. I have asked for more data, unseen and new - to test my model on that. However, once again the question was about the technical aspect of it and not about how production ready my code was.

Comment: @SamarjeetKaur There's a good research on problems with reproducibility of deep learning, so what I am saying isn't opinionated (or at least should not be). Back to the subject matter: remember that this community can help you only if you provide sufficient level of information. For instance, if you don't mention preprocessing, we assume none. You shared too little information for me to help. I can only wish luck :).

Comment: Also, I really appreciate your critical eye for this. Hence, if you can suggest some ways to validate this - given the limited data constraints, I'll be extremely grateful. I have asked for more data, new data and I'll get some, hopefully. But apart from that, any other way I can validate this - please do share. Thanks alot!

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'd love to share more information but I can't do it publicly, unfortunately :(.  Thanks for your help though! The discussion was enlightening.